# Select and Filter tidyverse functions sudden errors

Tags: r, dplyr

New persistent error: 'Error in select_impl(.data, vars)' with `filter` and `select` functions in `tidyverse`

I have already checked the `tidyverse` Github repository for updates, but I have not seen anything regarding these change. I have only had this error today despite months of using these functions the same way. I also tried converting the data from a `tibble` to a `data.frame`, reinstalling `dplyr/tidyverse`,  but that did not help either. Here is my code:

```
  projects %>% dplyr::select(
    WRK_WORK_ID,
    WRK_LOB_PORTFOLIO,
    WRK_STATUS,
    WRK_ACT_EFF_HRS_OVERALL,
    WRK_ACT_START_DT,
    WRK_ACT_FINISH_DT,
    WRK_WORK_TYPE
  )


activities = activities %>%
  dplyr::filter(`Work Status` == 'Completed' & `Work Type`
                %in% c('Product Releases',  'New Development',
                       'Minor Enhancements'))
```

I expect to only get those columns for the first lines but I get an error message:

> Error in select_impl(.data, vars) : 
>     SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'

For the second lines trying to filter the error is almost the exact same:

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
>     SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'

a small reproducible example shows the same results

```
data = data.frame(col1 = c(rep('first value', 5)), col2 = c(rep('second value', 5)))
> data
         col1         col2
1 first value second value
2 first value second value
3 first value second value
4 first value second value
5 first value second value
> data = data %>% dplyr::select(col1)
Error in select_impl(.data, vars) : 
  SET_VECTOR_ELT() can only be applied to a 'list', not a 'symbol'
```

Comment: Have you tried not mixing and matching your quote types (right ticks and left single quotes) such as `Work Status` == `Completed`? Tidyverse makes decisions on how to translate your objects but you are naming them in two different ways. I assume that we are missing code because you are filtering on `Work Status` but in the select statement you have `WRK_STATUS` which is not at all the same.

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible.  I am not getting any error with `dplyr_0.8.3` (with the updated example)

Comment: dplyr version is 0.8.3.  I have tried only using one quote type and it does not work still as the simple reproducible example above shows. This exact script worked yesterday, and all of the sudden this morning any use of these functions does not work despite no apparent package updates.

Comment: Try on a fresh R sesion

Comment: Fresh R session fixed it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to updating an R package and not restarting R/RStudio. Restart your session to resolve.